# When using object destructuring assignment, why is a property "name" cast to string?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given

```js
let obj = {name: 1};
console.log(typeof obj.name, obj.name); // `"number"`, `1`
```

Why is `name` identifier cast to string when using `var` at object destructuring assignment?

```js
let obj = {name: 1};
var {name} = obj; 
console.log(name, typeof name); // `1` `string`
```

But not using `let` or `const`?

```js
let obj = {name: 1};
let {name} = obj; 
console.log(name, typeof name);
```

We can avoid this unexpected result by defining a different identifier

```js
let obj = {name: 1};
var {name:_name} = obj; 
console.log(_name, typeof _name);
```

though curious as to the significance of `var` returning different results than `let` or `const` for the `name` identifier at a browser environment?

Comment: Is this behavior consistent across engines?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes. chromium 58 and firefox 53 at *nix, 32 bit, produce same result. Have not tried at safari at mac or edge at *indows.

Comment: @torazaburo Surmised related to `window.name`. Though why different results for `var` and `let`, `const`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behaviour is defined by the scope in which the code is being executed.

`name` refers to [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/name) property, which descriptor has a setter [to convert it to string](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context-name) when being assigned as `window.name = 1`:

> A valid browsing context name is any string with at least one character that does not start with a U+005F LOW LINE character. (Names starting with an underscore are reserved for special keywords.)

When being executed in global scope, `var name = ...` assigns a value to `window.name`. While `let` and `const` declare block-scoped variables.

When being executed in local scope, `name` will refer to local variable in both cases:

```
(() => {
 var obj = {name: 1};
 var {name} = obj; 
 console.log(typeof name); // 'number'
})();
```

Comment: The solution is to use block scope and `"use strict"` to avoid unexpected results?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes. Function scope is enough. That's the reason why we used to use all these IIFEs everywhere - to not clash with global scope. I removed 'use strict' from the snippet for clarity. It is desirable by default but won't affect the result, so it's not relevant here.

Comment: Is this behaviour, of `var` that is, one of the reasons `let` and `const` were developed and implemented? And a reason to avoid using `var` now that the former are now available for usage at browser environments?

Comment: @guest271314 Yes, it is. Nowadays if there's a need for global, we do `window.foo = ...`. Accidental assignment to global with `var foo = ...` is never desirable. Actually, intentional assignment to global with `var foo = ...` isn't desirable too, because it won't work in strict mode.

Comment: I wouldn't call global `let`/`const` declarations "block-scoped".

Comment: @Bergi I guess this should be addressed in terms of execution contexts instead, eh?

Comment: @estus I'd just call it "global scope". If you want to use spec terminology, it's "lexical environment" though not "execution context".